# systemd-boot partition not recognised as bootable

Tags: arch-linux, systemd-boot

Installing Arch to an old ASUS G74Sx with a Samsung SSD as the main system drive and a Seagate for data

I've partitioned and installed system to `/dev/sda` for systemd-boot as so:

```
root@archiso ~ # parted -l 

GNU Parted 3.6
Using /dev/sda
...    
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32              boot, esp
2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4

....


root@archiso ~ #  fdisk -l /dev/sda

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32              boot, esp
2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4
```

Configures systemd-boot as so:

```
# blkid
...
/dev/sda2: UUID="4b3bca9b-c49f-4414-abd4-96b02c66cd8c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d46a8ce3-6a36-4e22-8713-5f8a23c4c471"
/dev/sda1: UUID="F948-C4C3" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="6879733a-9c2c-4a9a-8093-875e2c25a111"
...

AFTER arch-chroot /mnt

root@archiso loader]# cat loader.conf
#timeout 3
#console-mode keep
default arch
timeout 4
console-mode max
editor no

[root@archiso loader]# cat entries/arch.conf
Arch Linux
linux   /vmlinuz-linux
initrd  /intel-ucode.img
initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
options root=PARTUUID="d46a8ce3-6a36-4e22-8713-5f8a23c4c471" rw
```

But startup prompts for a boot disk. Please, where is the error?

For @telcoM

```
root@archiso ~ # efibootmgr -v 
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
error trace:
```

EFI is enabled in BIOS

Running the installer and issuing that command gives a different result

```
    root@archiso ~ # efibootmgr -v
    ** Warning ** : Boot000a is not UEFI Spec compliant (lowercase hex in name)
    ** Warning ** : please recreate these using efibootmgr to remove this warning.
    error trace:
    BootCurrent: 000A
    Timeout: 0 seconds
    BootOrder: 000A,0001,0002,0000
    Boot0000* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)
        dp: 05 01 09 00 02 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    Boot0001* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)
        dp: 05 01 09 00 03 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    Boot0002* asmt test HD(1,MBR,0x5cfcc5eb,0x185000,0x7800)/File()
        dp: 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 50 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 eb c5 fc 5c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 / 04 04 06 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    Boot000a* UEFI: USB USB Hard Drive  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x5cfcc5eb,0x185000,0x7800)
        dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 00 1d / 03 05 06 00 01 00 / 03 05 06 00 03 00 / 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 50 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 eb c5 fc 5c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 / 7f ff 04 00
```

Comment: Please add the output of `efibootmgr -v` to your question post. Also, have you mounted `/dev/sda1`? Where is it mounted? Did you run `bootctl install`, and if so, was `sda1` mounted at that time?

Comment: @telcoM Ah. Thank you. EFI not enabled! Yet it is enabled in the BIOS. So... That's weird. I've installed to this machine before using systemd-boot, but something is amiss this time. Yes to both your questions. The /boot directory looks as I expect. I'll poke about but do you have any ideas?

Comment: @telocom Okay I'm running the installer again and getting another message from efibootmgr. I'll add it.